# What's the difference in roles of GATA-2 and BMI-1 in guiding Hematopietic cells?

Tags: molecular-biology, hematology, stem-cells, transcription-factor, differentiation

I've discovered that hematopoietic cells become lineage-positive (Lin+) and go down the path of becoming lymphoblasts and myeloblasts, and that both BMI-1 and GATA-2 are transcription factors that play a role in that.

What is the specific difference in the role of BMI-1 and GATA-2 in guiding a hematopoietic cell down either of those lineages?